# Is there a second-order priority problem in deontology?

Tags: reference-request, deontology

In *A Theory of Justice*, John Rawls brings up the notion of priority problems in ethics, and addresses (at length) two in particular: the definitional relation of the right and the good, and the political ordering on his two principles of justice. In this, he hearkens back to Kant's introduction of the right/good question in the second Critique (but which Scotus perhaps anticipated in his contrast between the [*affectio commodi* and the *affectio iustitiae*](https://plato.stanford.edu/entries/duns-scotus/#WilFreMor)), and then also the ordering on the maxims of practical reason delineated in *Religion within the Limits of Reason Alone*.

Actually, my interpretation of Rawls altogether is that he understood deontological ethics to be a matter of such "priority problems" through and through, hence his capitulation of the representative citizen's ordinal, and not cardinal, standing (*AToJ*, 1999 ed., pg. 79). Accordingly, I have over the years been on the "lookout" for *other* such problems. Three cases I've identified are:

1. The priority of redemption (or positive amendment) over retribution. This issue is implicit in the history of Christian hamartiology, explicit in the psychological fantasy stories of Stephen R. Donaldson (esp. his last relevant novel, *The Last Dark*).
2. Doing vs. allowing harm.
3. Creation and destruction.

Kant's way of setting up such problems is to identify any horn of such polylemma as rational on its own terms, so that it is not a matter of factoring some or another horn out of the question. Evil or wrongfulness in itself is not the lowest thing on a priority list, as if evil is to be done just in case everything else has been done first. Evil/wrong are not on the same such list at all. Nevertheless, the "act" of drawing up such lists in the wrong way, is the *sine qua non* of deontological wrongness.

**Question:** but what about a priority problem *over other priority problems?* This would be an ordering on approaches to the first-order priorities. For example, we might say that the first set of categories to balance is {doing, allowing}, then {right, good}, and so on towards Rawls' {equal liberty, {difference principle}} in descending order of abstraction. *On the other hand,* we might think that all the first-order problems can be resolved simultaneously, or that there are different second-order problems that are themselves coordinated under a third-order heading, or maybe it doesn't even matter what higher order is imposed on the base. Nevertheless, in looking for an architectonic for deontology, I see this as a promising vector of inquiry. It doesn't clearly show up in Kant or Rawls themselves, but are there more up-to-date deontological ethicists investigating this kind of possibility? (Note: I promise to look through opensource essay sites for relevant material, on my own time, anyway; but prior familiarity with such material, on the part of other PhilosophySE contributors, would be appreciated.)

Comment: Higher-order priority problem in deontology was perhaps emphasized a lot throughout Buddhism ancient and contemporary such as hinted in [Shurangama sutra](http://www.cttbusa.org/shurangama/shurangama15.asp.html) as "Buddha's summit": *when the three conditions of the karma of killing, stealing, and lust are cut off, the three causes for them do not arise. Then the madness of Yajnadatta in the mind ceases of itself, and just that ceasing is Bodhi...You can hold in memory the twelve divisions of the sutras spoken by the Buddhas of the ten directions...as many as the sands of the River Ganges...*